# How does an LDAP Client eg Apache Directory Studio get schema from an LDAP Server?

Tags: ldap, schema, ldap-client

I understand that LDAP Clients request for Schemas in a series of search requests.

I need to understand the exact sequence in which the client makes the calls to the server, and what the server returns as a result.

Can anyone explain or point to where I can look for this information?

Comment: Both questions here are off topic. Congrats.

Answer (score 0):

For MOST LDAP server implementations, you can follow the information supplied at https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/LDAP%20Query%20For%20Schema

This would output the schema into a LDIF file.